# Temporary loading screen

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent

First I have to admit that I am a beginer with the android programing and may not understand things correctly.

Secondly, the problem:
In my app, I've created a loading screen, and with a theard I have tried to restrict the time of this screen so when the time is over - it's move via intent to another screen.

The code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ImageView iv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen);
    iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgBtn1);
    iv.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.loading_i_animation);
    iv.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


public void onClick(final View iv) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

    AnimationDrawable anim=(AnimationDrawable) iv.getBackground();
    anim.start();

        }
    });

    t1.start();
    try {
        t1.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    t1.stop();

    //The moving to the other screen

    Intent st=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Welcome.class);
    startActivity(st);


} }
```

The intent itself work, as well as the animation of the loading_screen. However when I writed "t1.stop();" in order to stop the thread - it earsed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand. I forgot to use `finish()` and to proceed I have the option of "finally".

Correct code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ImageView iv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen);
    iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgBtn1);
    iv.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.loading_i_animation);
    iv.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(final View iv) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            AnimationDrawable anim=(AnimationDrawable) iv.getBackground();
            anim.start();

        }
    });
    t1.start();
    try {
        t1.sleep(1000);
        finish();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        Intent st=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Welcome.class);
        startActivity(st);
    }




}   
}
```